# converting an array column to a new column bigquery sql

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm trying to convert an array column into a new column. I've tried finding other questions that are similar to my situation but I've failed to find an answer.

This is my current table:

| date | id | emotion |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-10-01 | AB | frustration |
|  |  | anger |
| 2020-10-01 | ABC | anger |

My desired table output is this:

| date | id | emotion | emotion2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-10-01 | AB | frustration | anger |
| 2020-10-01 | ABC | anger | null |

Thanks for your help in advance.

P.S. There are six types of values in the emotion column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider another approach shown in below example

```
with `project.dataset.table` as (
  select date '2020-10-01' date, 'AB' id, ['frustration', 'anger'] emotion union all
  select '2020-10-01', 'ABC', ['anger']
)
select date, id, 
   'frustration' in unnest(emotion) frustration,
   'anger' in unnest(emotion) anger,
   'disgust' in unnest(emotion) disgust,
   'fear' in unnest(emotion) fear,
   'happiness' in unnest(emotion) happiness,
   'sadness' in unnest(emotion) sadness
from `project.dataset.table`
```

with output

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want separate columns, you can just reference the array:

```
with t as (
     select '2020-10-01' as date, 'AB' as id, array['frustration', 'anger'] as emotions union all
     select '2020-10-01', 'ABC',    array['anger'] as emotions
)
select t.date, t.id,
       emotions[safe_ordinal(1)] as emotion_1,
       emotions[safe_ordinal(2)] as emotion_2,
       emotions[safe_ordinal(3)] as emotion_3,
       emotions[safe_ordinal(4)] as emotion_4,
       emotions[safe_ordinal(5)] as emotion_5,
       emotions[safe_ordinal(6)] as emotion_6
from t;
```

I will add:  I think arrays are more useful than having repeated columns.  If the issue is that you want to export the data to a Google sheet, you might want `array_to_string()` to instead convert the value to a string.

Comment: thanks for the advice. first off, I'm facing an error like this "Element access using [] is not supported on values of type STRING"

Comment: the reason why i'm trying to make a new column is because i'm trying to extract an output when the emotion values are consecutively repeated based on different dates. however, i can't do this when the emotion column is an array. it becomes inaccruate.

Comment: @hustlecorean . . . This runs fine and does exactly what your question is asking for.  I can't think of a simpler method to do this.  You want to fetch a value from an array; indexing the array is the way to fetch it.

Answer (score 0):

A solution could be to flatten the table and pivot it on the `emotions` column. The advantages of this is that by setting an higher value for the `max_columns` it will automatically adapt to any new emotion.

I am using Felipe Hoffa pivot stored procedure to do this.

1. Flatten the table

```sql
create or replace table `project_id.dataset_id.emotions_flat` as (
select
    * except(emotions)
from `projet_id.dataset_id.emotions_table`
let join unnest(emotions) as emotion
)
```

2. Pivot it

```sql
call `fhoffa.x.pivot`(
    'project_id.dataset_id.emotions_flat'
    , 'project_id.dataset_id.emotions_pivotted'
    , ['date', 'id']
    , 'emotion'
    , 'emotion'
    , 5 -- This is the max number of columns (in your case the distinct emotions but can be higher than that)
    , 'any_value' -- this is the "aggregation", in your case you just want the emotion name and because it is the same value that generate the column it will always been the same value.
    , '' -- without limit)
;
```

This example require a real table but you could write your own pivot code to do it on the fly.